# Nested For loop not reaching the end of my matrices

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, indexing, nested

I am using a nested for loop to do the following functions:
I am going column by column in a TranLog matrix (W X N size) and finding which row has a non zero value
Based upon the row location of this non-zero Value in TranLog, I am calling the vector associated with that row # in the matrix Order.

The for loop is as follows:

```
for jj=1:W;
    for ii=1:N;
        if TranLog(ii,jj)>0.5
            test=Order(ii,:);
        end
    end
end
```

When I am running this the number of vectors output are smaller than it should be. For example: If Tranlog is 23X5 and Order is 23X6,  if there are 23 non zeros spread throughout the TranLog matrix (there is one non-zero value per row in TranLog) I am only getting 13 ouput vectors from the Order matrix. I am not sure why this isn't running to completion, I don't receive an error but it doesnt ouput as many vectors as I am expecting.

Comment: It might be helpful to include a tag to indicate the language you're using.

Comment: It looks to me as if your loops will iterate over an `N * W` array, rather than a `W * N` array, given the order of indices in the term `TranLog(ii,jj)`.

Comment: Your code is posted exactly in [this very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919153). This is either a _duplicate account_ or you have the same homework assignment. Bad form either way!

Comment: The Q&A @chappjc points to make it clear that this is indeed a duplicate question from a duplicate account.  Seriously bad form.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem. Your matrix has *W* rows and *N* columns, yet the *W* index, *jj*, is indexing columns rather than rows in line 3. The opposite is happening with *ii*, the index of *N*. Switch those around and you should be good to go!

```
for jj=1:W;
    for ii=1:N;
        if TranLog(jj,ii)>0.5
            test=Order(ii,:);
        end
    end
end
```